# Prevent Raspberry from blanking (console)

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspberry-pi2, raspberry-pi3

Is there any way to prevent the rasberry console from getiing black after a while?

I use only the console without any GUI. I already tried the following, but it didnt work at all :(

```
/etc/kbd/config
BLANK_TIME=0
POWERDOWN_TIME=0
```

Would be very greatful for any hints

Comment: Did you restart after changing settings? Also, are you using raspian? Do you know what version?

Comment: Yes, i restartetd it. Im using Raspian and Noobs in the newest version.

Answer (score 1):

Type this...

```
sudo sh -c "TERM=linux setterm -blank 0 >/dev/tty0"
```

Add this line to the bottom of your ~/.bashrc file to have the blank screen disabled on boot.